# Laravel 9 : Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have two models: User and Tier. In my management rules, A user is associated with one or more Third Parties, and a Tier is associated with a single User.

Here is what I wrote in my template:

**User Model**

```
public function tiers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tier::class);
}
```

**Tier Model**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,"user_id");
}
```

And when I try to retrieve the name of the User associated with the Tier as follows:

```
{{$tiers->user->name}}
```

But I have an error like this:

> Attempt to read property "name" on null

does anyone have an idea, please?

Comment: One of possible reasons could be you allowed deleting user model/object without cascading to delete child(ren) objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "Attempt to read property 'name' on null" suggests that the `user` relationship on the `Tier` model is returning `null`. This means that there is no `User` associated with the `Tier` in your database.

You should check your database to ensure that the `user_id` foreign key in your `tiers` table is correctly set and points to an existing `User`.

Also, before trying to access the `name` property on the `user` relationship, you should check if the relationship is `null`. Here's how you can do this in your Blade template:

```php
{{ $tiers->user ? $tiers->user->name : 'No User' }}
```

In this code, `$tiers->user ? $tiers->user->name : 'No User'` checks if `$tiers->user` is not `null`. If it's not `null`, it outputs the user's name. If it is `null`, it outputs 'No User'.

Answer (score 0):

If the relation is defined properly and you're facing issue Then you can simply tackle this error with the below approach:

```
1) {{$tiers->user?->name}}
2) {{optional($tiers->user)->name}}
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/monish-khatri/1e526e419c1a1d8adc38a205a75cf536